# Installation software on red hat by ansible playbooks

Tags: ansible

Hi I am looking for some suggestion how to install software by ansible.
I need to respond to prompts (after I run script for installing an application I get prompt message about: localisation for the application and localisation java). 
Can you tell which module of ansible can help in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Expect module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/expect_module.html) is made exactly for this task, you may also want to look at [expect utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) if for some reason you need to solve such tasks in bash

Comment: Thank you for your help.